# How to complete the'create a personas for the coffeehouse project'on google Coursera UX design course 2

Tags: google-chrome, user-experience, createprocess, coursera-api

How to complete the Google Coursera UX design course 2.
Creating personas for a coffee house project.

I tried creating a persona for the Google Coursera UX design course but was scored 0.0%,I am expecting steps to flow and how to pass that step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the criteria of the Google course, but do have a lot of experience with personas. Here are a few things you might be encountering:

1. Personas need to be based on details from real people who you believe will benefit most from using a product or service you help deliver. Personas are not just a list of demographic information, though those details can be relevant. For a coffeehouse project, looking at many perspectives, you'd want to think about customers who swing by, customers who stay a while, customers in groups, customers with special needs, employees working different stations, etc.
2. Describing a persona well includes capturing elements like context of use, emotions and attitudes, current ways of doing what you hope they will do with your product or service. Looking at the list above, you'd want to thinking about people on their way to work, in the middle of errands, trying to work or study in the shop, meeting a friend to chat, and more.
3. Focus on just 1 to 3 key personas. Many products are used by a variety of personas, from multiple user types to executives and buyers. Do research to uncover which ones are most connected to unlocking and delivering the benefits of the product/service. For example, commuters might be most important in the morning, and students in the afternoon.

Perhaps that will be helpful. If not, please reply with or edit your question to include more specific detail about the problems you are running into. Maybe include an example or two of the questions you have not been able to answer correctly.

Also, there are several really great books related to creating persona profiles. Reading one of those might be good, as well.